# Jenkins JEP-200 workaround for Windows

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am trying to run a Performance Center build job in Jenkins, and have hit a JEP-200 issue with the job. The Jenkins website does suggest a workaround, which is to run the Java instance with a -Dhudson.remoting.ClassFilter option.

Unfortunately, I am running our Jenkins instance as a Windows service, installed following the Jenkins install process. I can't see a method of adding the workaround option to the service.

I have tried stopping the service and running the full command as suggested;

```
java -Dhudson.remoting.ClassFilter=SimpleDateFormat -jar jenkins.war
```

While this did start Jenkins up, it proceeded to run the full set up process and overwrite some of the config files. I have now fixed the config files but I'm guessing this approach is wrong.

How can I add the `-Dhudson.remoting.ClassFilter=SimpleDateFormat` option to the windows service?

Answer (score 0):

Following this through I now have two options;

1. Ignore the error. It only appears when I apply or save the changes, it doesn't actually stop the build job from running.
2. Wait for the fix to arrive. At the same time as posting this I also posted to the Jenkins Jira ticket that was open, the person who wrote the plugin acknowledged the issue and is looking to whitelist SimpleDateFormat.

So I'm able to continue with the error in place for now, then get rid of it completely very soon. The Jira ticket does contain an updated version of the HPE plugin, I recommend that if you're in the same position with the JEP-200 issue that you take that version first. It can be found [here.](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52366)